# Client Application not receiving String output from the Server Application

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I intend to have server application to send String object to the client

application, and have it print out what was sent, until what was sent from

server equals to "stop".

The source below is the Server application,

```
/*

   Server application

*/
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class FunServer{

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket link = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection has been established");

        //Read
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(link.getInputStream());
        //Write
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream());
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String send;

        while(true){

            System.out.println("Please, enter your input.");
            send = keyboard.nextLine();

            if(send.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
                break;
            }
            wrter.println(send);
        }

        link.close();   

    }   
}
```

and the source below is the client application.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class FunClient{

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {

            String output;

            InetAddress local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket link = new Socket(local, 1234);
            System.out.println("Connection Successful.");

            Scanner reader = new Scanner(link.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream());

            while(true){

                output = writer.nextLine();

                if(output.equals("close")){
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(output);

            }

            link.close();

    }
}
```

After the user inputs a valid String, nothing is printed out in the client

application.

Am I using the Scanner and the PrintWriter in a wrong manner?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand what the `Socket.getInputStream()` and  `Socket.getInputStream()` do. `Socket.getInputStream()` returns an InputStream that you can read from to obtain data that was sent to you *from* the peer. You never read from your socket's inputstream on either the client or the server, so you never see anything sent by the peer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will go play around with those concepts.